# Why can't I echo "!" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I tried the following just now:

```
echo "Hello World!" > hw.txt
```

And I got this error:

```
bash: !": event not found
```

I tried `escaping` the `!` like this:

```
echo "Hello World\!" > hw.txt
```

But `hw.txt` contains:

```
Hello World\!
```

Now I tried:

```
echo "Hello!World" > hw.txt
```

and I get this:

```
bash: !World": event not found
```

**But** when I tried this:

```
echo "Hello ! World" > hw.txt
```

To my surprise it worked!

So I **also** tried this: (Note the `space` at the end.)

```
echo "Hello World! " > hw.txt
```

Why does bash treat `!` like this, even within quotes? And how does it work with a `trailing space`? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Use __single quotes__.

Comment: Why the downvote? It was an honest question. I didnt know it. Although a single quote does it. Multiple questions still lie un-answered.

Comment: @devnull Why doesnt it work with double quotes? And how come it works when I have a trailing space?

Comment: It doesn't work with double-quotes because strings inside double quotes are interpolated and `bash` history expansion feature kicks in which tries to execute the last command beginning with `"`.

Comment: And, BTW, I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @devnull I felt you didnt. Thats why I put that in a separate comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is specified in the bash man page under the **HISTORY EXPANSION** section:

> History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history
>   expansion character, which is `!` by  default.  Only  backslash (`\`) and
>   single quotes can quote the history expansion character.
>
> Several characters inhibit history expansion if  found  immediately 
>   following the  history expansion character, even if it is unquoted:
>   space, tab, newline, carriage return, and `=`.  If the extglob shell
>   option is enabled, `(`  will  also inhibit expansion.

and:

> If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!`  appearing
>   in double quotes is escaped using a backslash.  The backslash
>   preceding the `!` is not removed.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes for strings that should not be meddled with:

```
echo '!'
```

Use double quotes for strings that can be meddled with:

```
echo "$PWD"
```

Comment: This advice looks solid! :)

Answer (score 3):

The trailing space disables the Bash event designator `!`.

```
man bash | less -Ip 'Event Designators'

# An  event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the his-
# tory list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events  are  relative  to
# the current position in the history list.
# 
# !     Start  a  history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
#       newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option
#       is enabled using the shopt builtin).
```

Another way to disable the event designator `!` is to use:

```
set +H  # ... or ...
set +o histexpand
help set
```